# Maximize $\ x+\frac32 y\ $ subject to...

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I am stuck on the following problem:

> Consider the linear programming problem:
>
> Maximize $x+\frac32 y$
>
> subject to  $$2x+3y \le 16, \\ x+4y \le18,\\ x \ge 0,y \ge0.$$
>
> If $S$ denotes the set of all solutions of the above problem,then  which of the following options is correct?
>
> 1. $S$ is empty
> 2. $S$ is a singleton
> 3. $S$ is a line segment
> 4. $S$ has positive area

My Try:  [image]

I have drawn the lines and see that $Z_A$(where $Z$ is $x+\frac32 y)$=Value of $Z$ at $A=8$. Similarly, $Z_B=8,Z_C=\frac{27}{4},Z_D=18$. Now, I can not decide as according to my calculation , option 2 is the right choice but the answer key says ,the answer will be option 3. Can someone enlighten me? Thanks and regards to all.

Comment: The function to be maximized is $ \ x \ + \ \frac{3}{2} y \ $ , which has the same slope as one of the constraint equations, $ \ 2x \ + \ 3y \ = \ 16 \ $ .  So the maximum value is 16, occurring everywhere on the segment from AB.  (You don't generally see this happen in linear programming problems.)

Comment: The feasible region is the quadrilateral under both diagonal lines and bounded by the axes.  The maximum value of your objective function will occur at one of the four corners.  Evaluate the function at each, and find the largest by inspection.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner, good catch.

Comment: @SammyBlack Something of a trick question: the function to be optimized usually doesn't have the same slope as that of any of the constraint boundaries.

Comment: I see I need to revise two details in my comment above.  The maximum value for the _specified_ function is $ \ \frac{1}{2} (2x + 3y) \ = \ \frac{1}{2} \cdot 16 \ = \ 8 \ $ .  The other constraint $ \ x \ + \ 4y \ \le \ 18 \ $ still has to be met, so the solution points fall on the line $ \ 2x \ + \ 3y \ = \ 16 \ $ from the intersection point down to point A, the right side of the bounded quadrilateral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed it, $(x,y)$ can only be in the pink area.
Obviously, the maximum will be reach on the blue or orange edge.
So you need to calculate the value for both side and you'll find max = 8 is reached on the blue side, which is a line segment.
[image]

Comment: Oops, yes, 8: I forgot to divide the constant in the constraint equation by 2 in my comment above.

Comment: The value doesn't matter, the way of thinking is the main purpuse ;)

Comment: Thanks @Fabien for the explanation. Can you please let me know how to draw geometrical figure like you have drawn in your post by sharing important links from where I can learn it..

Comment: I'm afraid to disappoint you since I've used Paint for the previous figure. Sorry mate :/

Answer (score 0):

Your area is the common area of these two inequalities, i.e. the area near origin. Name that $OAPC$ where $P$ is intersection of $AB,CD$.

Also note that what you want to maximize has same equation as in first constraint. Hece, all points on $PC$ satisfy and hence...